# Launching Mathematica 11 kernel through double SSH

Tags: kernel, remote-access, kernel-startup

I'm trying to connect to a server in my university to do some computations. The problem is that I first need to login to one server through SSH and then from this one go to the "computation" server (I can't go to the computation server alone, unfortunately). I can use MobaXterm to do this, but I don't know how to do this in Mathematica. I'm using (in MobaXterm):

```
ssh -X login@serveraddress1
```

and then

```
ssh -X login@serveraddress2
```

I've read a tutorial on setting up a kernel on a remote server on Mathematica, but it doesn't work since I need to connect twice through SSH. What can I do?